# Are connections to MariaDB closed automatically when using Spring Boot and Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, mariadb

I have a Spring Boot application that connects to a MariaDB database, and it was working fine until I realized that there were unmanaged connections to the database. The dependencies are managed using Maven. I attempted to log into the database using $ mysql -u root -p and was informed that there are too many connections. I was under the impression that the Spring Framework automatically closed the connections to the database. How does Spring/Hibernate manage the connections to MariaDB?

I've attempted to increase the max_connections in mysql, however I cannot log in to mysql due to the 'too many connections' error message. Most of the solutions I've found require that you first log in to mysql.

I think the problem may be within my application.properties file where I have specified spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto as validate. I did this such that hibernate would not modify the SQL for the creation of my tables. Perhaps using create-drop would solve the issue?

Relevant dependencies from pom.xml:

```
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-search-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

from application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=example-password

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "create-drop" the database
# schema will be automatically created afresh for every start of application
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
<<<<<<< HEAD
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
=======
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
>>>>>>> 353345d141a2f83e8155574a9c8bbc04805ee1ee
```

I've received the error message: "Too many connections" when trying to log into the mysql server.

Similarly if I try to run the application now using Maven I receive:

Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution: Too many connections

Comment: How are you getting connections?. Are you using JPARepository or entitymanager

Comment: I believe I'm using JPA, as within my Application.java file I have the @EnableJpaAuditing annotation above the Application class definition. Above my Article.java (where I define the Article table) I have @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class). The repositories for my tables extend the CrudRepository interface. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening session to database in every request then you have to close it yourself after completing your transaction like below.

```
Session mSession = mSessionFactory.openSession();
```

...

```
mSession.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not explicitly opening the database connections, and therein lies the problem. Since I'm not sure exactly where I'm opening them, I don't know where/how to close them. Please see my response to [asolanki's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694143/asolanki) comment above.